# read table from keyboard in python

Tags: python, pandas

I often use pandas to read table form file using

```
X = pandas.read_table('filepath',sep=' ')
```

that's when I input from file. But this time, I need to input a table from keyboard but don't know how?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) for Python 2 and [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) for Python 3